# Setup Apache Tomcat on Synology

Tags: tomcat, synology

I have an problem setting up an Apache Tomcat on my Synology DS1511+ server. The installing is no problem, but when i try `http://"serverAdress":7070` i can't log into the the manage section. I have altered the tomcat-user.xml in  `/var/packages/Tomcat/target/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/conf/` with this roles

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

But still the same problem. Any suggestions what the problem could be.
Best regard Morten Starck

Answer (score 7):

1. you need to ssh to the synology using root account with your default GUI password.
2. go to directory `/var/packages/Tomcat/target/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/conf/`
3. edit the file `Tomcat-users.xml`
4. stop and restart Tomcat server
5. now can login with your new account

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the code of the file `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

It is in the path `/var/packages/Tomcat7/target/src/conf`.

If there is any problem with the XML, you can check the log file: `/var/packages/Tomcat7/target/src/logs/catalina.out`

Answer (score 1):

1. Through Terminal/SSH session, open the /var/packages/Tomcat7/target/src/conf/tomcat-users.xml  file.
2. Ensure atleast below is available in that:

   ```
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/> 
   <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
   ```
3. Under Package Center in the Diskstation, restart Tomcat service (Stop and Start).

Now you should be able to login with username 'tomcat' password 's3cret'.

Reference: https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/128739